# Haskell IO - hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to comprehend haskell IO but this feature of stdin ultimately confuses me:
When I try to use some function like getContents, for example in:

```
let main = do x<-getContents; putStrLn x
```

I get the following error:

```
hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

How I am supposed to do any IO with this? Is there some fix, or should I look up for another analogical IO function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you to also investigate an alternative approach. There some inherent problems with `getContents` and similar operations:

1. You can have an invalid handle - a handle that is already closed. This is common in most languages, but we can do better. Ideally, we'd like to be sure that once we close a handle, we can't use it further.
2. `getContents` is a [lazy `IO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892653/1333025), which means (among other problems) that:

   - We have little or no control of [when (if) the handle is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2981582/1333025).
   - While we're processing the string returned by `getContents`, the data are read using lazy `IO` operations. This means that inside pure computations we can get `IO` effects and errors.

A safer alternative is to use another concept, called iteratees, [conduits](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview) or pipes. The idea is that you describe your components as things that read some input data and/or write output and then combine them together. This allows you to write very robust and elegant code.

Comment: TBH it is not "better" because it leads to inverse of control.

Answer (score 9):

`getContents == hGetContents stdin`. In fact `hGetContents` marks its handle (semi-)closed and this means anything attempting to read from stdin ever again will fail.

Take a look at [**After using getContents**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#faq-and-things-to-watch-out-for) in the [**Haskell User Guide**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/)

Comment: And rightly so, because even Haskell can't change the fact that what you type at the keyboard can be read only once.

Answer (score 5):

[This does not reproduce in normal operation](http://ideone.com/NM4imm)

If you try to use `getContents` from within `ghci`, as you seem to be doing, that's exactly what will happen when you use it the second time around. The first invocation will set the handle in the (semi)closed state, and all subsequent attempts to use it will fail.