# How to reuse efficiently input from stdin in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I understand that I should not try to re-read from `stdin` because of errors about [Haskell IO - handle closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18160807/683218)
For example, in below:

```
main = do
  x <- getContents
  putStrLn $ map id x
  x <- getContents     --problem line
  putStrLn x
```

the second call  `x <- getContents` will cause the error:

```
test: <stdin>: hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

Of course, I can omit the second line to read from `getContents`.

```
main = do
  x <- getContents
  putStrLn $ map id x
  putStrLn x
```

But will this become a performance/memory issue? Will GHC have to keep all of the contents read from `stdin` in the main memory?

I imagine the first time around when `x` is consumed, GHC can throw away the portions of `x` that are already processed. So theoretically, GHC could only use a small amount of constant memory for the processing. But since we are going to use `x` again (and again), it seems that GHC cannot throw away anything. (Nor can it read again from `stdin`).

Is my understanding about the memory implications here correct? And if so, is there a fix?

Comment: Yes, it has to keep all stdin in memory. I can't see how a fix would be possible: do you want your program to discard data and still have it available later? Maybe you are looking for something like `do x <- getContents ; y <- useMyDataSomehow x ; useMoreData y` ? Anyway your problem might be solved by the pipes/conduit libraries (at the cost of writing your program in the style required by those libraries)

Comment: You have it exactly right `do {cs <- getContents; putStrLn cs}` uses basically no memory,  `do {cs <- getContents; putStrLn cs; putStrLn cs}` accumulates all of `cs` the first time around. How you 'get around' this will depend on what you are doing. Do you literally want to `putStrLn` twice? Or e.g record length and print, or what?

Comment: Roughly speaking, I am looking to use Haskell to implement UNIX `tee` command or a variant of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct: If you reuse `x`, ghc has to keep it all in memory.

I think a possible fix is to consume it lazily (once).

Let's say you want to output `x` to several output handles `hdls :: [Handle]`. The naive approach is:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getContents
    forM_ hdls $ \hdl -> do
        hPutStr hdl x
```

This will read `stdin` into `x` as the first `hPutStr` traverses the string (at least for unbuffered handles, `hPutStr` is simply a loop that calls `hPutChar` for each character in the string). From then on it'll be kept in memory for all following `hdl`s.

Alternatively:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getContents
    forM_ x $ \c -> do
        forM_ hdls $ \hdl -> do
            hPutChar hdl c
```

Here we've transposed the loops: Instead of iterating over the handles (and for each handle iterating over the input characters), we iterate over the input characters, and for each character, we print it to each handle.

I haven't tested it, but this form should guarantee that we don't need a lot of memory because each input character `c` is used once and then discarded.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how your example works. But I probably need something more complex than the synchronized handlers here. For example, if I need to `reverse` or `sort` the stream in the second round? I guess somewhere down the line, it will break.

Comment: @tinlyx `reverse` and `sort` will force all the input to be accumulated, they are text-book non-streaming operations. Things like `length` or word count etc. will work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you think if I use e.g. `reverse` on a big stream, I'll get the same memory issue anyways, regardless of whether it's used on a second round?

Comment: Yes. Just `do {cs <- getContents; putStrLn (reverse cs)}` and anything like it will have to accumulate the whole input, even without a second use. Similarly `sort` can't proceed until it knows it has the smallest element, which might be the last.